# appending data frame to an existing csv files in python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, append, csv-write-stream

I have several data frames to append to a csv files in python. I am using the following code to achieve that but not luck yet.

```
  import csv as writer
  import pandas as pd

def append_list_as_row(list_of_elem):
        # Open file in append mode
        with open('my_file.csv', 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
            # Create a writer object from csv module
            csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
            # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
            csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)
    append_list_as_row(new_data_frame)
```

throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Why is the question tagged "dataframe", are you using pandas anywhere?

Comment: yes, the data I want to append to an existing csv file is a data frame.

Comment: Ok, so is `list_of_elem` a list of DataFrames? It would be helpful to clarify this as the variable naming is not very clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think u are Forget to Use csv.writer in `csvwriter` initialize.
try this

```
def append_list_as_row(list_of_elem):
# Open file in append mode
    with open('my_file.csv', 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
        # Create a writer object from csv module
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)
        csv_writer.close()
    append_list_as_row(new_data_frame)
```

And another question all of the frames it has one line?
if it is not u can use for into `with`.
like this

```
for line in list_of_elem :
    csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

And you forget to use a close file.